# Alternative for GPG signature to publish JAR in maven central

Tags: java, jar, maven-2, gnupg, jarsigner

I am new to JAVA development and was working to publish the JAR in maven central for open access. It was mentioned in offical [maven](https://maven.apache.org/repository/guide-central-repository-upload.html) page that artifacts must be signed using [GPG](https://www.gnupg.org/download/) signature , i would like to know is there any other alternative software to sign the JAR so that it can be published in Maven central other than GPG signature? Will appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the background of this question? Why can't you use PGP?

Answer (score 1):

All artifacts deployed to Maven Central must be signed by PGP/GPP.

You can use plugin https://www.simplify4u.org/sign-maven-plugin/ which don't use `gpg` for signing so you don't have to install `gpg` on all systems which use your project.

Using and configuration of `sign-maven-plugin` is very easy.